# Next.js request.geo property returns undefined

Tags: next.js13

Request.geo object coming in as undefined.  See more: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-request

Expecting the geo object to return a value.

```
//pages/api/checkUserLocation.ts

import { NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

const checkUserLocation = async (req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) => {
  try {
    // Vercel provides geo object by default.  If cloud platform changes use let ip = request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-For') for ip and a third party service to look up location.
    const userInUS = req.geo?.country === 'US';
    console.log(req.geo?.country, 'country');
    console.log(res, 'response')
    return res.status(200).json(userInUS);
  } catch (error:any) {
    console.error('Error:', error.message);
    return res.status(500).json(false);
  }
};
```